# Java memory map on 32 bit machine

Tags: java, memory, dictionary

I have a file of size 5 gb. I like to do memory map that file in Java. I understand one memory mapped portion can not be > 2 gb. 
My question is, Is it possible to create 5 x 1 gb memory mapped portions to map the complete 5 gb file and access them in the same Java application.

Comment: The reason for the 2GB limitation is MAX_INT (you need an integer in order to access an array). Though I don't understand the motivation what you suggest sounds doable.

Comment: If possible stream your data to process. Does it need to fit into memory all at once?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

There are two issues here:

- First of all, a 32-bit machine (or 32-bit OS on 64-bit machine) only has an address space of 4 GB (32 bits), so you can't map a 5 GB file all at the same time even from C.
- The other issue is the limitation of Java's implementation of memory mapping which is handled via a [MappedByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html). Even though the method [FileChannel.map()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map-java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode-long-long-) takes `long`s for offset and size, it returns a `MappedByteBuffer` which can only use `int`s for its limit and position. This means that even on a 64-bit machine and OS where you can map the whole 5 GB file as a single area from C, in Java you will have to manually create a series of mapped regions, each no larger than 2 GB. Still, you will at least be able to map the 5 GB in chunks while on a 32 bit OS you can't have them mapped at the same time. And given that in Java unmapping a file region requires some ugly tricks, it's not convenient (though possible) to map and unmap regions as needed in order to keep them within the limit. You can have a look at the source code of Lucene or Cassandra. As far as I remember they also use libraries with native code when possible in order to handle mapping and unmapping in a more efficient way than pure Java allows.

To make things even more complicated, 2 GB is the theoretical limit which may not be reachable on a 32-bit OS due to memory fragmentation. Some OS-es may also be configured with a 3-1 memory split which leaves just 1 GB of address space available to user-space programs, with the rest going to the OS address space. So, in practice, the chunks you should try mapping should be much smaller than 2 GB, you are more likely to succeed in mapping 4-6 chunks of 250 MB than in mapping a single 2 GB chunk.

Comment: You a wrong a bit. Firstly, there is sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl class with private methods map0 and unmap0 without 2GB limitation, if you want large memory mapped file on x64, then it's your choice. Secondly, nothing prevents you from creating more than 4GB (in summary) of memory mapped files, OS will handle it with swapping mechanism (but you will feel dramatic performance pitfall), so technically answer is "Yes, you can". Even more, "Yes, you can do it with one memory mapped portion"

Comment: Yes, you can use the internal APIs but it requires some ugly hacks and can at least in theory break with any next Java release. As for the 4 GB limit — no, you can't map more than 4 GB at the same time inside a single process on a 32-bit OS. There simply isn't enough address space to give each mapped byte its own address. This is not related in any way to whether the data will be loaded into RAM or not. There's not enough addresses in the virtual memory subsystem to map it at all.

Comment: Ok, I've misunderstood the view (as a part of file) and the whole file itself, I was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see [`MappedByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) and [`FileChannel.map()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long)) javadocs.

I'm not an expert in Java NIO, so I'm not sure if the *byte buffer* handles chunks automatically or if you have to use multiple `MappedByteBuffer`s. Feel free to code a simple class to test and play around with your huge file.